# Changing the output of a function in R

Tags: r, poisson

I have created a function to generate random poisson distributions but want the function to calculate the mean of lambda also.

`xpoisson<-function(x,mu){rpois(x, lambda=mu)}`

This is what I have written so far and Im not sure where/how to add `the mean(mu)` to the function. Any help apppreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is not `mean(mu)` but `mean(rpois(x,lamda=mu))` ?
If so, just add the new line inside the function, assign the distribution and mean to variables and return both values by adding them to a list and returning said list.

Answer (score 1):

Functions will only output one variable. In order to output two variables you need, for instance, to output them as a list. Try the following:

```
xpoisson<-function(x,mu){
  list(rpois(x, lambda=mu),mean(mu))
}
```